# How to structure a multi-tenant system in CockroachDB to ensure good performance?

Tags: performance, database-design, multi-tenant, cockroachdb

We have a multi-tenant system whose data we're starting to migrate to CockroachDB.
We will often need to join data belonging to a single tenant from across multiple tables. In more seldom cases, we will also read data belonging multiple/all tenants - but that doesn't happen as often, and thus is not as important seen from a performance perspective.

We thought [table interleaving](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/interleave-in-parent.html) *might* have been part of a good solution - i.e.: have a tenant "parent" table, and then interleave other tables into that table, to increase chance data belonging to same tenant end up in same range. But whether that was a good idea or not, doesn't matter now, as interleaving has been deprecated.

Creating a separate schema or database per tenant, might be one solution. But as we already have one schema per microservice, that would lead to an explosion of schemas (we have thousands of tenants). Thus some design with a "discriminator" column telling which tenant a given row of data belongs to is preferable.

What would be a good design, that is both nice to work with and has good performance? E.g. would it help to use composite keys with the tenant-ID as the first part of the key? I guess that might at least ensure that data from the same tenant in a single table is located next to each other, and thus more likely to end up in the same range? That won't help when doing joins across tables though (which is what I had expected interleaving to help with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Creating a separate schema or database per tenant, might be one solution. But as we already have one schema per microservice, that would lead to an explosion of schemas (we have thousands of tenants). Thus some design with a "discriminator" column telling which tenant a given row of data belongs to is preferable.

Either of these approaches will be appropriate in terms of performance. In fact, they'll result in very similar key encodings under the hood in CRDB's [distributed key-value store](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/architecture/distribution-layer).

That said, CockroachDB has a soft-limit of around 10k databases, so if you already have thousands of users, a database-per-user may be inadvisable.

So including a tenant-id as the prefix of each table's primary key and secondary indexes is likely the best approach. It will ensure that data from the same tenant in a single table is located next to each other for the purposes of optimizing scans and multi-row read-write transactions.

Comment: OK - so the way I understand your answer, by prefixing keys with tenant ID, we can do quick queries on a _single_ table when we filter by tenant ID. But when we join 2 different tables, the data may still be located in different ranges and thus on different nodes. That's one of the things I expected interleaved tables to help with.

Comment: Nathan, do you know if you plan any replacement for table interleaving to support multi-tenant tables? E.g. increasing chance that data belonging to the same tenant (and thus have the same primary key prefix) from 2 different tables will be located in the same range? Would make sense as we will often join data belonging to the same tenant across tables.

Comment: Prefixing keys with tenant IDs will allow for quick queries on one _or many_ tables when filtered by tenant ID. The thing you lose without interleaved tables is the ability to hit a fast-path where the join is translated into a single contiguous scan over all of a tenant's data instead of two separate, individually efficient, scans with a merge join combining their results.

Comment: However, we found that this fast-path was rarely beneficial in practice. It often led to scanning over extraneous data in other interleaved tables that were not needed to service a given query. Interleaved joins also eliminated an opportunity for parallelism. In our testing, we found that replacing interleaved joins with standard merge joins led to about a 50% speedup in most customer queries.

Comment: So my suggestion would be to prefix each index with tenant IDs and then include a tenant ID in each query and see how things perform. If you find performance issues, we would be very interested in hearing about them.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Just what I needed :-)